# Работа с коммитами и ветками

Tags: git

**1) Команда git status на сервере, в директории содержащей работающий проект, в ветке master выдаёт**:

> On branch master
>   Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 290 commits.

[image: Imgur]

Что это значит?
Нашёл ответ: local/master на 290 коммитов опережает remote/master. 
И... что же это всё равно значит?

Решение которое нашёл:

```
$ git pull origin mybranch
$ git pull origin
```

Должно вроде бы избавить от "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 290 commits."... не понимаю однако зачем делать pull, проект на сервере по идее соответствует тому что в репозитории, ведь это рабочий проект.

**2) Ветвь testing содержит много изменений, однако файлы на сервере в директории testing отличаются от того, что в репозитории.** Отличий много... чтобы не разбираться что к чему решено было скопировать файлы из ветки master в ветку testing.
Мануалы говорят примерно следующее "Надо переместить указатель HEAD на master, после чего в директории testing: git reset -hard и git pull
Верно ли это? Как скопировать всё из master в testing?

---

### --------------------------------- Updated -----------------------------------

Спасибо с п.1 разобрался. С п.2 проблемы...

Сделал

> git merge /origin/master

на сервере в папке с тестовой копией проекта. Далее надо так понимаю сделать git push, чтобы эти изменения были всем доступны (т.е. локал/оригин c тестового сервера затолкать в римоут/оригин). Но не даёт git push сделать:

> [rejected] testing ->
>   testing[non-fast-forward] To prevent
>   you from loosing your history,
>   non-fast-forward were rejected. Merge
>   the remote changes (e.g. git pull).

git pull думаю здесь не нужно, ведь скопировал ветку master на ветку testing (т.е. master to local/origin/testing)

git status сообщает:

> Your branch and 'origin/testing' have
>   diverged and have 272 and 5374
>   commit(s), each respectively

Попробовал на сервере в папке с тестовым проектом: git rebase /origin/testing
Выскакивают конфликты, понятия не имею что там за изменения в файлах и когда они делались, откатился от rebase назад.

Так понимаю если сделать git push -f избавит от описанных выше проблем, но потеряется история разработки, что не хотелось бы.
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как справиться с этими проблемами

Answer (score 8):

1) Гит - распределенная система, т.е. локально хранится копия репозитория. И вся работа строится так, что сначала изменения вносятся в локальную рабочую копию (команда commit), а потом передаются в удаленный репозиторий (команда push).

Ошибка

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 290 commits.
```

означает, что были сделаны 290 коммитов в локальной рабочей копии, но не отправлены в удаленный репозиторий. Чтобы они попали в удаленный репозиторий, нужно выполнить команду

```
git push
```

Если у вас такая информация пишется в рабочей копии на боевом сервере, значит кто-то правил файлы прямо там. Чтобы эти изменения были доступны всем, нужно выполнить push и вытолкнуть изменения в общий удаленный репозиторий

2) Команда

```
git reset --hard
```

Удаляет все незакоммиченные изменения. Чтобы скопировать изменения из одной ветки в другую, нужно воспользоваться командой

```
git merge branchname
```

Она сливает изменения из ветки branchname в текущую ветку. Переключаться между ветками можно командой

```
git checkout branchname
```

Переключение может не произойти, если есть незакоммиченные изменения. Их можно закоммитить

```
git commit
```

можно спрятать

```
git stash
```

при этом они перестают быть видны, пока не будет выполнена команда

```
git stash apply
```

а можно сбросить как вы написали - командой reset

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но снова проблема возникла, diverged branches. Подскажите, пожалуйста как исправить. Свой пост отредактировал, описав дальнейшие мучения

Comment: @east, git pull выполните, т.к. в удаленном репозитории есть изменения, которых нет в локальной ветке, об этом вам сам гит подсказывает. Это сольет изменения из удаленной ветки origin/testing в текущую testing (возможно, потребуется разрешить конфликты и выполнить после этого коммит). После этого выполните git push, это вытолкнет все локальные изменения в origin. После этого изменения станут доступны для других локальных репозиториев, которые настроены на этот же origin.

Comment: Вообще, если у вас все изменения делались на боевом сервере, то есть там сейчас актуальная версия кода, то ничего страшного в git push -f нет. Эта команда затрет (условно, т.к. из репозитория гита ничего из закоммиченного реально не удаляется) те изменения, которые есть в удаленном репозитории на этой ветке, но которых нет в локальной ветке.

Comment: мерджите и ребейзите с локальными ветками, а не удаленными, путаницы будет меньше. т.е. вместо

    git merge /origin/master

выполняйте примерно такую последовательность

    git checkout master # переключились на ветку master
    git pull master # вытянули изменения и смерджили их с текущими в ветке
    git checkout testing # вернулись на ветку testing
    git merge master # слили изменения с локального мастера в testing
    git pull # вытянули изменения из origin/testing и слили их с теми, что есть в локальной ветке testing
    git push # вытолкнули изменения на testing в origin/testing